# How to improve SqlBulkCopy performance with Azure SQL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlbulkcopy

When I run a program on local DB to insert 100,000 records. It take around 2 seconds to import. After switch to Azure SQL the time increase with high percentage of DTU.

This is my code

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServer()))
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            connection.Open();

            var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
            using (var sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, transaction))
            {
                // SET BatchSize value.
                sqlBulk.BatchSize = 150000;
                sqlBulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 60;
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Master_Transaction";
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dataTable);

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine($"database running time {ts}");
        }
```

I test with Azure SQL using DTU purchased plan after testing the result are

- 10 DTU    37 seconds
- 20 DTU    24 seconds
- 50 DTU    18 seconds
- 100 DTU   15 seconds

Even running time is decreased. The avg_log_write_percent is still high and DTU is also high as pictures below:
[image]
[image]

My question are

- How can I improve the performance of SqlBulkCopy with Azure SQL?

  - by fixing code program
  - by configuring the azure resource
- Can I decrease the DTU max and reduce avg_log_write_percent?

Notes

- the table have clustered index key

Comment: See if it's possible to supply the input sorted by the clustered index key; if so, you can use `.ColumnOrderHints` property to specify that it is, which saves a sort step in tempdb. Another thing that's generally worthwhile if we're talking TDS over a long-distance TCP/IP connection is to override the default `PacketSize` in the connection and set it to the maximum value (32767) -- this often works wonders in terms of transmission speeds. Last but not least, if you're going to be inserting 100K rows, a `DataTable` is very inefficient in terms of memory (and filling it); aim for a `DataReader`.

Comment: A high time for log file writing suggests that your database is using the full recovery model, rather than the simple or bulk logged model, which incurs high overhead for bulk inserting specifically. As I understand it from some quick searching you can't make Azure use any other recovery model than full (but I'm not an expert), so if you're comparing it to a local database that doesn't use full recovery, you're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: It worths to mention that DTU is a combination of CPU, memory and I/O. So 10DTU is literally nothing, specially if you're using the database at the same time you're doing the Bulk operation (expect timeouts and other sql errors if that's true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the service tiers you have used on your tests are based on remote storage (S0 to S3), that means you may see performance degradation on IO intensive tasks. Meanwhile, Premium tiers are based on locally attached SSD storage and that provides higher IOPS and throughput than Basic/Standard tiers.

In addition to the storage related limitations of the S0 to S3 tiers, on all these tiers query plans are serialized, all queries execute with max degree of parallelism = 1. Don't expect good performance on IO and CPU intensive tasks on those service tiers.